# Is there a way to import Python3's multiprocessing module inside a Sublime Text 3 plugin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm making a ST3 plugin on my OSX dev-environment, but according to the [unofficial docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/plugins.html):

> Sublime Text ships with a trimmed down standard library. The Tkinter, multiprocessing and sqlite3 modules are among the missing ones.

Even if it's not bundled with ST3, is there a way I can still import `multiprocessing` ([docs](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/multiprocessing.html))? Is there a way I can import it as a "standalone" module inside my plugin dir?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you intend this program for wide distribution, it's probably unreasonable to expect users to install Python 3 in a standard location in order to use your work. However, depending on Python's redistribution license, you may be able to get away with just bundling `multiprocessing` with your plugin. If your main `my_awesome_plugin.py` file is in the root of your plugin directory, put the full `multiprocessing` directory in as a subdirectory and you should be able to `import multiprocessing as mp` just fine. Fortunately it's pure Python, so you don't have to worry about platform-specific distributions.

---

***EDIT***

OK, my bad. After a little more exploring around the `...lib/python3.3/` hierarchy, it turns out there ***is*** a compiled `_multiprocessing.so` library in there to supplement the pure Python version. So, this will be a little more difficult than just dropping in the `multiprocessing` directory. I still think it might be doable, as you could theoretically include the compiled library for the three different ST3 platforms, then put in some logic to determine what OS the user is running. However, I'm not as up to date on the Python internals as I would need to be to properly answer this question, so I'll defer to someone else on exactly how that could work.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've made a plugin with ST3 before, but plugins are  isolated from external Python installs so it doesn't matter if users have Python installed or not. You can't import standard libs from any Python except the one bundled with ST3. So there's no need to fire up a VM because just attempting to import `multiprocessing` on *any* computer gives you a `module not found` error. Are you sure the Python 3 `multiprocessing` is pure python? I haven't found anything that indicates it is or isn't.

Comment: OK, I'm going to need to modify the answer - turns out I was missing the `...lib/python3.3/lib-dynload/` directory, and there ***is*** a `_multiprocessing.so` file in there. Rats. I suppose you could make platform-specific versions of your plugin...